# How to install Ubuntu on a spanned volume

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have been using Ubuntu for quite a while but am running low on space as I only allocated 50GB. 
As a workaround, for now, I have mounted another drive in which I have stored some contents.
I have installed Ubuntu on SSD and the drive I have mounted is an HDD.
I have mounted the drive as `/mnt`.
I wish to reinstall Ubuntu but this time I would like to install it in some sort of spanned drive. I would like `/` to consist of both SSD and HDD
Any solution is accepted as long as I don't out of space in the future because now I have to store some things in `/mnt` and some in `/home`, can't there be a way in which I can use both in the same way.
Can somebody guide me on how to do so?

Comment: This will be difficult to answer *correctly* without knowing how you use your system. There is always the “Something Else” option when using the installer to set up partitions but, depending on how you use your system, it’s a challenge to say which top-level (or second level) directories should be on SSD while others are on the spinning rust. If you’re comfortable with creating partitions, moving data, and mounting locations, then I would see this as an opportunity to learn how Linux systems treat storage and just how much flexibility you have without the need to reinstall from scratch 

Comment: I am a java developer currently, I use the system for regular stuff, nothing really special, I have not installed Ubuntu using lvm so I can't merge `/mnt` and `/home`, merging those would be like a dream but I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging volumes to install an operating system will be highly complicated and make the system more vulnerable. Your current setup is fine. Storing data on another disk is *not at all* a workaround. It is a perfectly viable solution to expand space for data storage.

You can very efficiently and easily organize data storage in Linux using symbolic links. Thus, you can easily and seamlessly access any data from within your home directory, even if it is stored on another partition.

Suppose you have a "Music" folder taking a lot of the 50GB. Move that folder to the `/mnt` directory on the other drive. Now create a symbolic link "Music" in your home directory that points to the real Music directory under `mnt`: now you can access your Music from within your home directory just like before.

To create a symbolic link:

*Method 1: using Files*

- Open two windows of Files, one open where your moved "Music" folder is, and one open in your home directory, where you want to create the link.
- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. Drag the Music folder to the other pane and release the mouse button: a symbolic link "Music" will be created that, for all daily uses, acts and feels like a real directory.

*Method 2: terminal*

Use the `ln -s` command to create symbolic links, e.g the command to create a symbolic link "Music" in your home directory that refers to the real folder "Music" on the mounted disk.

```
ln -s /mnt/Music ~/Music
```